Project reactor upgrade from v2 to v3?
Is there really no official project reactor upgrade guide from v2 to v3?
I've searched far and wide, even using waybackmachine, but I've had no luck finding any upgrade path documentation from v2 to v3 (v2.0.6.RELEASE to v3.5.15, to be more precise).
Now, I'm aware that I'm coming in a bit late with this question, given that the first v3 came out somewhere in 2017, but the current version is still v3, so I guess it shouldn't be too late, right?
The best resource I've found so far is this GH issue comment, but I have several other questions.
Specifically, what do I use in v3 instead of these v2 classes:

reactor.core.Dispatcher
reactor.core.dispatch.SynchronousDispatcher
reactor.core.dispatch.RingBufferDispatcher
reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor (the comment I linked to above says reactor.core.publisher.TopicProcessor, but that too has since been removed)
reactor.rx.action.Action
reactor.rx.stream.GroupedStream (I assume reactor.core.publisher.GroupedFlux, since Stream -> Flux, but what do I use instead of GroupedStream.lift?

Thanks.

OK, let me answer each of the items from my question with a separate answer (for readability reasons) in the hope that it might help others in the future.

Dispatcher -> Scheduler
SynchronousDispatcher -> Schedulers.immediate()

Old:
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import reactor.core.Dispatcher;
import reactor.core.dispatch.SynchronousDispatcher;

public final class ReactiveEventRouter {
  // dropping unimportant, unchanged parts and field modifiers for brevity
  SynchronousDispatcher syncDispatcher = new SynchronousDispatcher();
  CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscription<?>> subscriptions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
  reactor.fn.Consumer<Throwable> errorConsumer = (th) -> log.error("Error while processing event", th);

  public <E> void tryRoute(final Object event, Subscription<E> 
subscription, Dispatcher dispatcher) {
    if (subscription.test(event)) {
      dispatcher.dispatch(event, subscription::accept, errorConsumer);
    }
  }

  public <E> void tryRoute(final Object event, Subscription<E> subscription) {
    tryRoute(event, subscription, syncDispatcher);
  }

  public void route(final Object event) {
    route(event, syncDispatcher);
  }

  public void route(final Object event, Dispatcher dispatcher) {
    subscriptions.forEach(subscription -> {
      if (subscription.test(event)) {
        dispatcher.dispatch(event, subscription::accept, errorConsumer);
      }
    });
  }
}

New:
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public final class ReactiveEventRouter {
  Scheduler immediateScheduler = Schedulers.immediate();
  CopyOnWriteArrayList<Subscription<?>> subscriptions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
  Consumer<Throwable> errorConsumer = (th) -> log.error("Error while processing event", th);

  public <E> void tryRoute(final Object event, Subscription<E> subscription, Scheduler scheduler) {
    if (subscription.test(event)) {
      Mono.just(event)
          .subscribeOn(scheduler)
          .doOnError(errorConsumer)
          .doOnNext(subscription::accept)
          .subscribe();
    }
  }

  public <E> void tryRoute(final Object event, Subscription<E> subscription) {
    tryRoute(event, subscription, immediateScheduler);
  }

  public void route(final Object event) {
    route(event, immediateScheduler);
  }

  public void route(final Object event, Scheduler scheduler) {
    subscriptions.forEach(subscription -> {
      if (subscription.test(event)) {
        Mono.just(event)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .doOnError(errorConsumer)
            .doOnNext(subscription::accept)
            .subscribe();
      }
    });
  }
}

JFYI: a simple inner class ReactiveEventRouter.Subscription hasn't changed, but I'm including it here to avoid confusion with org.reactivestreams.Subscription:
public static class Subscription<E> {
  final Predicate<Object> matcher;
  final Consumer<E> consumer; // this is java.util.function.Consumer

  Subscription(Predicate<Object> matcher, Consumer<E> consumer) {
    this.matcher = matcher;
    this.consumer = consumer;
  }

  boolean test(Object obj) {
    return matcher.test(obj);
  }

  void accept(Object evt) {
    consumer.accept((E) evt);
  }
}


I could've used TopicProcessor, since it's still there, in v3.5.15, but I couldn't stomach using a deprecated class which should've already been removed in v3.5, so I gave Sinks a try, but didn't have time to deeply study all aspects of Sinks.

RingBufferProcessor -> Sinks.Many

Old (snippets):
import reactor.core.processor.RingBufferProcessor;
import reactor.fn.Function;
import reactor.rx.Stream;
import reactor.rx.Streams;
import reactor.rx.stream.GroupedStream;

// fields with modifiers removed
// uses com.lmax.disruptor.LiteBlockingWaitStrategy
RingBufferProcessor<REvt<E, R>> processor = RingBufferProcessor.create();
Function<GroupedStream<VGrp<R>, REvt<E, R>>, Stream<PRes>> stream;
Function<REvt<E, R>, VGrp<RULE>> makeGroup;

private void start() {
  Streams.wrap(processor)
      .groupBy(makeGroup::apply)
      .flatMap(stream)
      .observe(this::alertObserver)
      .consume();
}

public void accept(REvt<E, R> evt) {
  processor.accept(evt); // this calls org.reactivestreams.Subscriber#onNext
}

New (snippets):
import java.util.function.Function;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.GroupedFlux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks;

// fields with modifiers removed
Sinks.Many<REvt<E, R>> eventSink = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
Function<GroupedFlux<VGrp<R>, REvt<E, R>>, Flux<PRes>> stream;
Function<REvt<E, R>, VGrp<RULE>> makeGroup;

private void start() {
  eventSink.asFlux()
      .groupBy(makeGroup)
      .flatMap(stream)
      .doOnNext(this::alertObserver)
      .subscribe();
}

// this is the part I'm most skeptical of
// how else would you retry failed events?
// my thinking was: given that the whole pipeline is not fully event driven
// i.e. asynchronous, it might make sense to block in some place indefinitely
// until the roadblock is cleared
public void accept(REvt<E, R> evt) {
  while (eventSink.tryEmitNext(evt).isFailure()) {
    try {
      // is busy-waiting for .5s like this before retrying OK?
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}



Action
Instead of each Action I implemented a custom FluxOperator. I'm not providing any code examples, because the interface is very similar, so it's fairly straightforward.

Stream -> Flux
GroupedStream -> GroupedFlux.


Wherever the lift method was called, we now call transform:
Old:
// from is a GroupedStream
from.lift(() -> new CancellingAction<>(reactEvt -> ...))

New:
// from is a GroupedFlux
from.transform(flux -> new CancellingOperator<>(flux, reactEvt -> ...))



RingBufferDispatcher -> Schedulers.boundedElastic()

Old (snippets):
import reactor.core.dispatch.RingBufferDispatcher;

private final RingBufferDispatcher ringBufferDispatcher = new RingBufferDispatcher("reactive-event-engine");

public void forwardEvent(Object event) {
  router.route(event, ringBufferDispatcher); // the router is ReactiveEventRouter from the answer which addressed items 1. and 2.
}

New (snippets):
import reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

private final Scheduler eventScheduler = Schedulers.boundedElastic();

public void forwardEvent(Object event) {
  router.route(event, eventScheduler);
}

